# C# Issues when getting another script

Tags: c#

So I have been following a Youtube tutorial for fence building and I have done everything. The only issue is now it wont work, 2 functions are saying that one of my variables pointer isn't defining them even though in the tutorial it worked, here is my script

```
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Reflection;

public class CreateFence : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int Building = 1;
    bool creating;
    ShowMousePosition Pointer;
    public GameObject polePrefab;
    public GameObject fencePrefab;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Pointer = GetComponent<ShowMousePosition>();
    }



    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
    void getInput()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && Building == 1)
        {
            startFence();
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            setFence();
        }
        else if (creating)
        {
            updateFence();
        }
    }
    void startFence()
    {
        creating = true;
        Vector3 startpos = System.Reflection.Pointer.getWorldPoint();///getWorldPoint says Pointer has no definition for it
        startpos = System.Reflection.Pointer.snapPosition(startpos);///snapPosition says Pointer has no definition for it
    }
    void setFence()
    {
        creating = false;
    }
    void updateFence()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe the tutorial has this exact code. Why would something from the .NET base class library have those method members? I think you are confused about what `Pointer` is. More likely you are looking for `Point`, or similar.

Comment: Ok, it was a YouTube tutorial, thanks I will try that, it didn’t work

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out, it was the system reflect thing, apparently unity autocorrected me incorrectly, Apple = Microsoft Visual Studios